# Simple CMOS switch with weird voltage in LTSpice

Tags: voltage, mosfet, ltspice

I am new to all this, so please forgive me, as I feel the answer to this must be so simple.

I tried to build a basic CMOS switch. It has a supply of 5 V. There are periodic pulses of 5 V supplied to the input.

[image]

I expected the output to alternate between 0 V and 5 V. After running the simulation, I was surprised to find out that it alternates between 0 V and 620 mV.

[image]

Either I am not understanding things correctly, or there is something wrong here. Why am I not seeing 5 V on the output?

Comment: Swap the transistors or the psu voltage. nmos shall be upper, and pmos lower. M1 goes to vcc, M2 to gnd.

Comment: Swapping the transistors results in like outputs, as opposed to opposite outputs. Changing the PSU voltage has very little effect. 3 V doesn't change, 9 V doesn't change, and for kicks I even tried 240 V.. picked up to 800 mV in the output.

Comment: Did yo place transistors orientation exactly as shown in my answer?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I commented on your answer.

Comment: Do you mean switch or inverter? What you've shown looks more like an inverter; but with Drain and Source of the N-MOSFET swapped. If you really mean "switch" then I'd expect something like a [transmission gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_gate).

Comment: There are already two answers about the position of the transistors, but you shouldn't rely on the default values for them, they are, most likely, not what you expect. So you should always either modify the MOS parameters, or choose a model, or subcircuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body diode of the NMOS is conducting, clamping the voltage to 620 mV when the PMOS is turned on (also conducting).

You should rotate the NMOS 180 degrees as shown in left picture.
But to draw a schematic correctly, you should actually put Vcc on top, and GND at the bottom (right picture).

[image]

Note the pictures for the mosfets in LTspice have the both an arrow. If you cut the arrow loose from the gate and reconnect it to the other terminal of the mosfet (drain) the arrow shows how the body diode is connected (shown in red in left picture).

Comment: But between spikes they are not both conducting, are they? When the output is 620 mV, that means the output is connected to the voltage source, not ground, so the PMOS should be conducting and the NMOS shouldn't. No?

Comment: Rotate the NMOS?? According to this image, and others, they should be "pointing" the same way, shouldn't they? https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdieB.png

Comment: @JaredBrandt Ill update my answer to clarify

Comment: How does that change anything? That's just the gate, isn't it? I can't even find an option in LTSpice to do that.

Comment: Select the NMOS (by pressing F7), rotate it twice (CTRL+R) and mirror it (CTRL-E)

Comment: The linked picture (i.stack.imgur.com/BdieB.png) and your schematic are identical. Bt for **both** applies that the body diode of the NMOS will be conducting when the PMOS is driven (such the the PMOS is conducting).

Comment: Oooh, didn't even notice the source and drain were switched! I did try to take that advice, but it resulted in a constant output of 2.5 V.

Comment: My apologies!! I must have rotated the wrong thing, or the wrong way, or something... I just tried this solution again and it worked! I am now getting an inverted 5 V. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f435CA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I think you better have the NMOS at the bottom and the PMOS on top, so the Vgs for both mosfets is independent of the OUT. In this setup, OUT is floating (or pulled down/up by the leakage currents of the mosfets, but I wouldn't rely on leakage currents...). Moreover, if I (almost) short OUT to ground, it will fail turning on the mosfets.

Comment: @Huisman That's the correct orientation of MOSFETs, others have issue regarding cross conduction. Your proposal to have upper PMOS and lower NMOS results in a inverter circuit, it would be a NC switch, mine is a NO switch.

Comment: Constructing this circuit results in perfectly synchronized input and output voltages..

Comment: OP has a inverter circuit... But am I correct that driving the mosfets in this configuration relies on the leakage current? I mean, otherwise the sources would be floating, though?

Answer (score 0):

The ONLY functional error is the NMOS source connected to the output instead of ground=0V which logically must at the bottom of the schematic and +ve supply at the top.

There is slight cross-conduction at Vdd/2 but both body diodes are always OFF.  When we have complementary transistors arranged this way, we call it an inverter, as “**All single transistor switches (of all types) are always inverting”**  and this example has 2 switches not one. So it is a misnomer to call the circuit a switch.  In a different arrangement with complementary drivers we can make both conduct or not, then we call its function an Analog switch.

So 3 corrections in all; functional, logical presentation and semantics

Good question, but learn to verify your assumptions for accuracy.

When I started in ‘75, I always had an EE who was not as technical, yet far more careful to check my drawings and he would often find one or sometimes many things in error or missing.  A good drawing is understood by any level of skill and obeys the polarity of common sense. “P ‘drain’ supplies from Positive, N ‘source’ Sinks from Negative.”